# replacing curly brackets and text in it with node

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
var str="Hello my name is {john/www.john.com} and welcome to my {site/www.site.com}."
```

i have extracted curly brackets and made an anchor tag out of them like

```
<a href="www.john.com">john</a>
```

What i am trying to do is replace curly brackets and content in them with these nodes.
Is it possible using regExp? I have studied regExp on MDN but still cant figure out the way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure it is:

```js
var str = "Hello my name is {john/www.john.com} and welcome to my {site/www.site.com}.";

str = str.replace(/\{(.+?)\/(.+?)\}/g, function(m, label, url) {
    return '<a href="http://' + url + '">' + label + '</a>';
});

document.write(str);
```

The regex is:

```
\{(.+?)\/(.+?)\}
```

- `\{` matches `{`
- `(.+?)` matches and captures anything (as few chars as possible, so up to the first `/`)
- `\/` matches `/`
- `(.+?)` matches and captures anything up to `}`
- `\}` matches `}`

Comment: this is excellent answer. But i would like to ask about that anonymous function you passed as callback. How come it it exctract name/url paramater? I have never seen such a things in regExp.

Comment: @trolkura when you pass a callback to the `replace` function, the first parameter is always the match (here it's `m`). The following parameters are variable arguments equal to `m[1]`, `m[2]` and so on, as a convenience. I could have used `m[1]` instead of `label` and `m[2]` instead of `url` but using the variable arguments and giving them a name makes the code more readable.